# Don Sobao la colodra

Tags: significado

Quisiera preguntar el significado de “colodra” en “[Don Sobao la colodra](https://www.carrefour.es/supermercado/sobaos-don-sobao-340-g-don-sobao/R-750302653/p)”.

Según la RAE, colodra es un “recipiente de madera que llevaba un segador sujeto a la cintura con una correa, para guardar la pizarra con que debía afilar la guadaña.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La definición que citas no está recogida del DLE sino del Oxford Dictionary - que es el que muestra Google -, como podemos constatar si consultamos ambos diccionarios online.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/colodra)

> Recipiente de madera que llevaba un segador sujeto a la cintura con una correa, para guardar la pizarra con que debía afilar la guadaña.

[DLE](https://dle.rae.es/colodra)

> 4. f. **Cantb**. y Pal. Funda de cuerno o madera con agua, que lleva el segador colgada a la cintura para colocar la pizarra de afilar el dalle.
>    Has omitido un detalle importante de la definición recogida en el DLE

La definición recogida en el DLE nos indica un detalle importante, que la acepción cuarta se usa sobre todo en **Cantabria** y Palencia.

Si consultamos en la Wikipedia el término [sobao](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobao) tenemos que

> El **sobao** o sobao pasiego es un producto de repostería típico de la
> comarca de los Valles Pasiegos (**Cantabria**, España). Su popularidad ha
> hecho que sea unos de los productos más reconocidos y comercializados
> de la gastronomía de **Cantabria**.

Resumiendo, colodra es una palabra típica de Cantabria, como los sobaos son un producto típico de Cantabria. El nombre de marca o de empresa *La Colodra* muy posiblemente ha sido escogido para destacar la relación de su producto con la región española.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones otra vez!

Comment: @Maurice de nada :-)